# How to display images from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, blob

I want to display images from my MySQL database to an website that I'm working on but when I visit the site I see just a box with a broken image or lot of symbols.

In my MySQL database the image type is `LONGBLOB` (MIME: image/jpeg).

This is the code that I'm using (I have HTML codes before the PHP codes so I'm using a buffer).

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('connection error');
mysql_select_db("produse");


$per_page = 25;
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM filtrederetea");
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset($GET['page'])) ? (int)$GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page -1) *$per_page;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filtrederobinet");
echo "<table>";
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filtrederetea");
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $imagedata = $query_row['img'];
        '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($query_row['img']);
    };
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo "($imagedata)";
}
else
    echo "error";


while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo.$query_row["img"];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
?>
<img src=<?php echo $query_row["img"]; ?> width="130" height="130">
<?php
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

if ($pages >=1) {

    for ($x=1;$x<=$pages;$x++) { 
        echo '<a href="?page'.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
    }
}
ob_end_flush()
?>
```

Comment: You are missing something after $imagedata = $query_row['img']; - the next line starts with '<img src= ...

Comment: remove this: `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

Comment: and what i`m missing?

Comment: nope nothing happend by removing the header

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that storing images in a database is generally a bad idea. Not only does it clutter up your database with large, cumbersome binary objects, but it eliminates a lot of the efficiencies of serving files off of disk directly. Whenever practical, store the files on disk and a reference to the stored path in the database. Even better, use an object-store like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to offload the storage.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' on line 34

Comment: there is no error on line 34